# Summing over lists of arbitrary levels of nestedness in F#

Tags: haskell, f#

I'm trying to create an F# function that will return the sum of a list of `int`s of arbitrary nestedness. Ie. it will work for a `list<int>`, a `list<list<int>>` and a `list<list<list<list<list<list<int>>>>>>`.

In Haskell I would write something like:

```
class HasSum a where
    getSum :: a -> Integer

instance HasSum Integer where
    getSum = id

instance HasSum a => HasSum [a] where
    getSum = sum . map getSum
```

which would let me do:

```
list :: a -> [a]
list = replicate 6

nestedList :: [[[[[[[[[[Integer]]]]]]]]]]
nestedList =
    list $ list $ list $ list $ list $
    list $ list $ list $ list $ list (1 :: Integer)

sumNestedList :: Integer
sumNestedList = getSum nestedList
```

[Link to runnable code](https://replit.com/@runeksvendsen/WastefulBiodegradableJumpthreading).

How can I achieve this in F#?

Comment: I don't know F# enough -- I don't know if it supports something like Haskell's typeclasses. In the worst case, you should be able to pass explicit dictionaries even if it's not as convenient as in Haskell where the compiler infers the right dictionaries for you. The F# code in such case would be something like `getSum (dictList (dictList (..... (dictList dictInt)))) nestedList` where the number of `dictList` matches the number of `[]` in the type of `nestedList`.

Comment: Could you make this haskell code runnable on a REPL?

Comment: here you go...  https://repl.it/repls/BlondCoolParallelport

Comment: F# don't have type classes (https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/243). I tried the operator overloading trick that in theory could work but I just managed to crash the compiler but perhaps you can make something of the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376001/418488

Comment: It is possible to solve this using reflection but I don't think this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I cannot imagine any realistic F# codebase where you would need this. What was your motivation for doing this? I would probably change the design so that you do not get into a situation like this - it will probably make your F# code better anyway.

Comment: @FilipeCarvalho I've added a link to a runnable piece of code to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE

I found a simpler version using an operator `($)` instead of a member. 
Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224269/4550898 :

```
type SumOperations = SumOperations 

let inline getSum b = SumOperations $ b // <-- puting this here avoids defaulting to int

type SumOperations with
    static member inline ($) (SumOperations, x  : int     ) = x 
    static member inline ($) (SumOperations, xl : _   list) = xl |> List.sumBy getSum
```

### The rest of the explanation still applies and it is useful...

I found a way to make it possible:

```
let inline getSum0< ^t, ^a when (^t or ^a) : (static member Sum : ^a -> int)> a : int = 
    ((^t or ^a) : (static member Sum : ^a -> int) a)

type SumOperations =
    static member inline Sum( x : float   ) = int x
    static member inline Sum( x : int     ) =  x 
    static member inline Sum(lx : _   list) = lx |> List.sumBy getSum0<SumOperations, _>

let inline getSum x = getSum0<SumOperations, _> x

2                  |> getSum |> printfn "%d" // = 2
[ 2 ; 1 ]          |> getSum |> printfn "%d" // = 3
[[2; 3] ; [4; 5] ] |> getSum |> printfn "%d" // = 14
```

Running your example:

```
let list v = List.replicate 6 v

1
|> list |> list |> list |> list |> list
|> list |> list |> list |> list |> list
|> getSum |> printfn "%d" // = 60466176
```

This is based on using SRTPs with member constraints: `static member Sum`, 
the constraint requires the type to have a member called `Sum`
that returns an `int`. When using SRTPs generic functions
need to be `inline`.

That is not the difficult part. The hard part is "adding" `Sum` member to 
an existing type like `int` and `List` which is not allowed. But, we can add 
it to a new type `SumOperations` and include in the constraint `(^t or ^a)` 
where `^t` is always going to be `SumOperations`.

- `getSum0` declares the `Sum` member constraint and invokes it.
- `getSum`  passes `SumOperations` as the first type parameter to `getSum0`

The line `static member inline Sum(x  : float   ) = int x` was added
to convince the compiler to use a generic dynamic function call and 
not just default to `static member inline Sum(x  : int     )` when 
calling `List.sumBy`

As you can see is a bit convoluted, the syntax is complex
and it was necessary to work around
some quirks on the compiler but in the end it was possible.

This method can be extended to work with Arrays, tuples, options, etc. or any combination of them by adding more definitions to `SumOperations`:

```
type SumOperations with
    static member inline ($) (SumOperations, lx : _   []  ) = lx |> Array.sumBy getSum
    static member inline ($) (SumOperations, a  : ^a * ^b ) = match a with a, b -> getSum a + getSum b 
    static member inline ($) (SumOperations, ox : _ option) = ox |> Option.map getSum |> Option.defaultValue 0

(Some 3, [| 2 ; 1 |]) |> getSum |> printfn "%d" // = 6
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/03rVWT

Comment: this is a great solution! but why not just recursion or fold?

Comment: Recursion and fold cannot handle varying types. When a generic recursive function is instantiated it fixes the type of the parameters. In this case every call to `Sum` is done with a simpler type: `Sum<int list list list>`, `Sum<int list list>`, `Sum<int list>`, `Sum<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the runtime version, would work with all .net collections. However, exchanges compiler errors in [AMieres' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60226525/637783) for runtime exceptions and AMieres' is 36x faster too.

```
let list v = List.replicate 6 v

let rec getSum (input:IEnumerable) =
    match input with
    | :? IEnumerable<int> as l -> l |> Seq.sum
    | e -> 
        e 
        |> Seq.cast<IEnumerable> // will runtime exception if not nested IEnumerable Types
        |> Seq.sumBy getSum


1 |> list |> list |> list |> list |> list
|> list |> list |> list |> list |> list |> getSum // = 60466176
```

Benchmarks

```
|    Method |        Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|---------- |------------:|----------:|----------:|
| WeirdSumC |    76.09 ms |  0.398 ms |  0.373 ms |
| WeirdSumR | 2,779.98 ms | 22.849 ms | 21.373 ms |

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  1 ms   : 1 Millisecond (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: It works well, although is noticeably slower: running it 10 times took 56 seconds compared to 1 second with the other solution.

Comment: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html