# F#, Entity Framework and nullable values

Tags: entity-framework, f#

This is an extremely difficult problem in F#, that is extremely easy in C#

I'm using a custom `DomainManager` to write an Azure Mobile App Table Controller in F#. The `DomainManager` inherits from `MappedEntityDomainManager<,>`, which uses Automapper under the covers to map my database objects into mobile-friendly records.

The Automapper profile looks like this:

```
type EventOrganiserProfile() =
    inherit Profile()
    do
        let nullDateTime = Nullable<DateTime>()
        base.CreateMap<MyDbEntity, MyMobileDto>() 
            ...
            .ForMember(fun dest -> dest.UpdatedAt, fun opt -> opt.MapFrom(fun src -> if src.CancelledUtc <> nullDateTime then src.CancelledUtc.Value else src.StartedUtc))
            ...
        |> ignore         
        base.CreateMap<MyMobileDto, MyDbEntity>() 
            ...
        |> ignore
```

`src.StartedUtc` is a `DateTime`, `src.CancelledUtc` is a nullable `DateTime`, and because its class inherits from `EntityData`, `dest.UpdatedAt` is a nullable `DateTimeOffset`.

This code compiles, but when I try to run it, I get the error message

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.DateTime Invoke(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

What this seems to be referring to is my use of the `.Value` property of `Nullable<DateTime>`. The underlying cause is F#'s rigorous type-checking. In C# this would have been handled seamlessly by the null coalescing operator `??`.

Is there a way to simulate null coalescing as part of an Entity Framework-friendly expression in F#?

Comment: What happens if you change your if block to `if src.CancelledUtc.HasValue`?

Comment: I need the value, so that won't cover my case.

Comment: You can define your null coalescing operator as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194565/null-coalescing-operator-in-f)