# Maybe coalescing operator

Tags: haskell, null, option-type, null-coalescing-operator

I'm wondering how I could go about defining an operator / if an operator already exists in Haskell that lets pick the first `Maybe` type that isn't `Nothing`, and if all if them are nothing, it returns some default. Basically something like this:

```
let x = a ?? b ?? c ?? 1
```

where `(??)` is the operator and `a, b, c` are all `Maybe` types. I'd expect this code to return the first value that is `Just` or `1` if all of `a, b, c` are `Nothing`.

I'm basically looking to replicate the same functionality as the null coalescing operator you'd find in `C#` or other languages.

This question shows how to do it in 
 F# ([Null Coalescing Operator in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194565/null-coalescing-operator-in-f)), and it's quite hacky. Is there a way to do it cleanly in Haskell, and if not, what's the closest you can get to it?

Comment: [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+Maybe+a+-%3E+Maybe+a) is a great tool for finding this kind of thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Haskeller's would generally use [`(<|>) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) for this sort of thing. Assuming `a, b, c :: Maybe Int`, you have `x :: Maybe Int`

```
let x = a <|> b <|> c <|> Just 1
```

Of course, that isn't really what you asked for. If you want, you could define it though!

```
-- You expect `a ?? b ?? c ?? 1` to parse as `a ?? (b ?? (c ?? 1))`
infixr 3 ??

-- (Someone is going to point out that `(??) = flip fromMaybe`, so I am first)
(??) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
Just x ?? _ = x
Nothing ?? y = y
```

Then, you get precisely the behaviour you expect. Assuming `a, b, c :: Maybe Int`, you have `x :: Int`:

```
let x = a ?? b ?? c ?? 1
```

Comment: your answer is better.

Comment: You can use `1` with `<|>` if you have a handy `instance Num a => Num (Maybe a)` lying around.

Comment: We can also use `asum` from `Data.Foldable` to combine a list of maybes using `<|>`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mind writing it differently?

```
safeHead [] d = d
safeHead (h:_) _ = h
```

then

```
let x = safeHead (catMaybes [a, b, c]) 1
```

shall do what you want.

If you want to do it in that way, it's doable, but two operators are required.

```
a@(Just _) ?? _ = a
_ ?? b = b

(Just e) ?: _ = e
_ ?: d = d
```

defines the two operators you need, and they work:

```
Prelude> let a = Nothing
Prelude> let b = Nothing
Prelude> let c = Just 3
Prelude> a ?? b ?? c ?: 10
3
Prelude> a ?? b ?? Nothing ?: 10
10
```

Comment: This works, but I think you're right in that I should be clear that I want it done specifically in the way I specified above. I'll edit it and add an example I saw in F# too.

Comment: @m0meni i don't program F# i am sorry. but i can show you how to do it with operators in haskell(but two operators).

Answer (score 1):

Just for some practicing purposes this job can also be expressed by the `Monoid` class type `First` which is a `Maybe` monoid returning the leftmost non-Nothing value.

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

infixr 3 ??

(??) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
x ?? y = fromJust . getFirst $ First x <> First (Just y)

*Main> Nothing ?? Nothing ?? 1
1
*Main> Nothing ?? Just 3 ?? 1
3
*Main> Just 7 ?? Just 3 ?? 1
7
```