# Multiple dispatch behavior for operator overloads

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, math.net

The following gives a duplicate definition error:

```
let (.*) (m1 : Matrix<float>) (m2 : Matrix<float>) =
    m1.Multiply(m2)

let (.*) (v1 : Vector<float>) (v2 : Vector<float>) =
    v1.DotProduct(v2)
```

Is there a way to define an operator overload such that F# recognizes the function I'm trying to call based on the function signature?

For example Julia has this very useful feature:

```
julia> methods(*)
# 138 methods for generic function "*":
*(x::Bool, y::Bool) at bool.jl:38
*{T<:Unsigned}(x::Bool, y::T<:Unsigned) at bool.jl:53
*(x::Bool, z::Complex{Bool}) at complex.jl:122
*(x::Bool, z::Complex{T<:Real}) at complex.jl:129
...
```

It would be great if there were a way to replicate something similar in F#.

Comment: F# does extensive type inference, and doesn't play nice with function/operator overloading. You will need to inline or put it in a class.

Comment: In fact it seems that you cannot overload operators in extension members...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functions with generic parameter types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501069/functions-with-generic-parameter-types)

Comment: Btw, I took a look at Julia, it's nice but obviously this is one its strengths: 'Julia programs are organized around multiple dispatch; by defining functions and overloading them for different combinations of argument types, which can also be user-defined. '

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case `*` is already overloaded. For example:

```
let m = matrix [[ 1.0; 4.0; 7.0 ]
                [ 2.0; 5.0; 8.0 ]
                [ 3.0; 6.0; 9.0 ]]
let v = vector [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]
let s = 5.

m * m
//val it : Matrix<float> =
//  DenseMatrix 3x3-Double
//30  66  102
//36  81  126
//42  96  150

v * v
//val it : float = 1400.0
```

**With overloading**:

```
type Mult = Mult with
    static member inline ( $ ) (Mult, m1:Matrix<float>) = fun (m2:Matrix<float>) -> m1.Multiply(m2)
    static member inline ( $ ) (Mult, v1:Vector<float>) = fun (v2:Vector<float>) -> v1.DotProduct(v2)

let inline ( .*. ) v1 v2 = (Mult $ v1) v2
```

And you can use it like this:

```
m .*. m
v .*. v
```

You'll get the same results as above. You can use `.*`, I just avoided it as not to get confused with the already defined `.*`. Now this is actually discussed in [Global Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682432/global-operator-overloading-in-f/) and [Oveload operator in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812084/overload-operator-in-f/) but F#'s behavior here is a bit obscure so I re-did the example with the Matrix and Vector types. You can probably make it generic. Maybe someone more familiar with mathdotnet can provide a more idiomatic solution. You should also check if `*` , `.*` et al. are already overloaded and function as expected for you since for common operations most of this stuff is [already implemented](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Arithmetics/).